# Connect4 Game Board

Tags: javascript, jquery, game

I'm looking for a review of my Connect4 game board. If there is anything I can do better, easier, shorter, etc., please let me know! If you need to see other files for the game, let me know as well.

```
var players = {};
var outOfTime;
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Game variables.
  var board,
      width = 7,
      height = 6,
      timePerMove = 2000,
      turn;

  // Cached jQuery selectors.
  var $board = $('.board');

  var init = function() {
    // Set up the board.
    board = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      var row = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        row.push(0);
      }
      board.push(row);
    }

    turn = 1;
  };

  var render = function() {
    $board.html('');
    for (var row = 0; row < height; row++) {
      var $row = $("<div class='row'></div>");
      for (var col = 0; col < width; col++) {
        var $cell = $("<div class='cell'></div>")
        $cell.attr('row', row);
        $cell.attr('col', col);

        var piece = board[row][col];
        if (piece) {
          var $piece = $("<div class='piece'><div>")
          $piece.addClass(piece === 1 ? "one" : "two");
          $piece.appendTo($cell);
        }
        $cell.appendTo($row);
      }
      $row.appendTo($board);
    }
  };

  var placePiece = function(col, color, b) {
    b = b || board
    for (var row = height; row--;) {
      if (b[row][col] === 0) {
        b[row][col] = color;
        return;
      }
    }
    throw "Illegal move."
  };

  var checkWinner = function(b) {
    b = b || board; // By default, evaluate the actual game board.

    var row, col, color;
    // check rows
    for(row = 0; row < height; row++) {
      for (col = 0; col < width - 3; col++) {
        color = b[row][col]
        if (color) { // four in a row of zeros doesn't count.
          if (b[row][col+1] === color && b[row][col+2] === color && b[row][col+3] === color) {
            return {
              winner: color,
              squares: [[row, col], [row, col+1], [row, col+2], [row, col+3]]
            };
          }
        }
      }
    }
    // check columns
    for(col = 0; col < width; col++) {
      for (row = 0; row < height - 3; row++) {
        color = b[row][col]
        if (color) { // four in a row of zeros doesn't count.
          if (b[row+1][col] === color && b[row+2][col] === color && b[row+3][col] === color) {
            return {
              winner: color,
              squares: [[row, col], [row+1, col], [row+2, col], [row+3, col]]
            };
          }
        }
      }
    }
    // check NW-SE diagonals
    for(col = 0; col < width - 3; col++) {
      for (row = 0; row < height - 3; row++) {
        color = b[row][col]
        if (color) { // four in a row of zeros doesn't count.
          if (b[row+1][col+1] === color && b[row+2][col+2] === color && b[row+3][col+3] === color) {
            return {
              winner: color,
              squares: [[row, col], [row+1, col+1], [row+2, col+2], [row+3, col+3]]
            };
          }
        }
      }
    }
    // check SW-NE diagonals
    for(col = 0; col < width - 3; col++) {
      for (row = 3; row < height; row++) {
        color = b[row][col]
        if (color) { // four in a row of zeros doesn't count.
          if (b[row-1][col+1] === color && b[row-2][col+2] === color && b[row-3][col+3] === color) {
            return {
              winner: color,
              squares: [[row, col], [row-1, col+1], [row-2, col+2], [row-3, col+3]]
            };
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return {winner: 0};
  }

  var endGame = function(result) {
    if (result.winner === 0) {
      console.log("TIE GAME");
    } else {
      console.log("PLAYER " + result.winner + " WINS.")
    }
  }

  var copyBoard = function(b) {
    b = b || board; // By default, copy the actual game board.
    var output = [];
    for (var row = 0; row < height; row++) {
      output.push(b[row].slice());
    }
    return output;
  }

  var printBoard = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      var output = "";
      for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        if (board[i][j]) {
          output += board[i][j] === 1 ? "x " : "o ";
        } else {
          output += "- ";
        }
      }
      console.log(output);
    }
  };

  var requestMove = function() {
    // Don't let two moves be made.
    var moveProvided = false;

    console.log("requesting move for player", turn);

    // Function to be called with a move.
    var attemptMove = function(col) {
      clearTimeout(outOfTime);
      if (!moveProvided) {
        moveProvided = true;
        try {
          if (col === -1) {
            console.log("oops! looks like you didn't move in time. making a random move.");
            throw "didn't move in time";
          } else {
          }
          placePiece(col, turn);
        // If the player's move is illegal...
        } catch (ex) {
          console.log("oops! looks like that move doesn't work. making a random move.");

          // Find all legal columns.
          var legal = [];
          for (var col = 0; col < width; col++) {
            if (board[0][col] === 0) {
              legal.push(col);
            }
          }
          // If there are any, make a random legal move.
          if (legal.length) {
            var choice = Math.floor(Math.random()*legal.length)
            placePiece(legal[choice], turn);

          // Otherwise, end the game in a draw.
          } else {
            endGame(0)
          }
        }
        render();
        var result = checkWinner();
        if (result && result.winner) {
          endGame(result);
        } else {
          turn *= -1;
          requestMove();
        }
      }
    }

    // Call the move function of the player who's turn it is.
    players[turn === 1 ? "red" : "blue"].move(attemptMove);
    //
    clearTimeout(outOfTime);
    outOfTime = setTimeout(function(){ attemptMove(-1);}, timePerMove);
  };

  window.printBoard = printBoard;
  window.copyBoard = copyBoard;
  window.makeMove = function(turn, col, board) {
    var board = copyBoard(board);
    try {
      placePiece(col, turn, board);
    } catch (ex) {
      return null;
    }
    return board;
  };

  // Init.
  setTimeout((function(){
    init();
    render();
    requestMove();
  }).bind(this), 500);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSLint/JSHint has helped me a lot.

JSLint may seem strange at first, but it helps you to write a code that has a architectural advantage from many different angles.

Main reason why JSLint and JSHint are so widely used is to uglify/minify your JavaScript code later as it prepares your code well for that purposes. This can save you a lot of bandwidth if your code base is huge.

It can also help you to parse through your own code later for whatever purposes, replace function for its contents, highlighting, etc...

Here is a link to Douglas Crockford JSLint website:
http://www.jslint.com/